# How to solve problem with wiremock on Jenkins? java.net.BindException: Permission denied

Tags: jenkins, junit, wiremock

I have problem with wiremock test failing on Jenkins. When I try to run it on my local it runs smoothly, but when I tried to run on Jenkins, this exception occured :

```
[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] ============================

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] ============================

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] Positive matches:

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] -----------------

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z]     None

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] Negative matches:

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] -----------------

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z]     None

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] Exclusions:

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] -----------

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z]     None

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] Unconditional classes:

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] ----------------------

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z]     None

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.562Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.670Z] [ThreadedStreamConsumer] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin - Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 7, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 48.407 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.dhl.subscriptions.boot.controller.NotificationsControllerITest

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.671Z] [ThreadedStreamConsumer] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin - testUpdateNotificationRuleStatus  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.761Z] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1845761c testClass = com.dhl.subscriptions.boot.controller.NotificationsControllerITest, locations = [], classes = [com.dhl.subscriptions.boot.SubscriptionsApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = ["test"], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@733f04ae key = [org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockConfiguration, org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockRestTemplateConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@497570fb, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51e37590, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@43255a5b, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@1c6e0a08, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@433e536f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@81319d4a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@5a9800f8, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@fecd68b1], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.761Z] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.761Z] Caused by: com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.FatalStartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:99

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.762Z] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:99

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.762Z] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:99

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.762Z] Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.762Z] 

[2023-10-09T12:20:41.762Z] [ThreadedStreamConsumer] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin - testGetNotificationRule  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
```

JUnit code is :

```
package com.dhl.subscriptions.boot.controller;

import com.dhl.security.aaa.adapter.keycloak.Authentication;
import com.dhl.security.model.User;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.boot.SubscriptionsApplication;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.db.entity.NotificationConfigEntity;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.db.entity.NotificationRuleEntity;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.db.entity.TagsEntity;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.db.entity.UserProfileEntity;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.db.repository.NotificationConfigRepository;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.db.repository.NotificationRuleRepository;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.db.repository.UserProfileRepository;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.db.repository.UserTagRepository;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.model.*;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.rest.api.NotificationsController;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.service.NaritaOperations;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.service.NaritaService;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.service.NotificationService;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.service.config.ConfigService;
import com.dhl.subscriptions.service.mapper.NotificationRuleMapper;
import com.dhl.track.commons.translations.TranslationsService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.AutoConfigureWireMock;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

import static com.dhl.subscriptions.boot.controller.DataUtil.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SubscriptionsApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 99, stubs = {"classpath:/stubs"})
public class NotificationsControllerITest {
    public static final String USER_EMAIL = "petr.kostroun@dhl.com";

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;
    @Autowired
    private NotificationConfigRepository notificationConfigRepository;
    @Autowired
    private NotificationRuleRepository notificationRuleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private NaritaService naritaService;
    @Autowired
    private NotificationRuleMapper notificationRuleMapper;
    @MockBean
    private Authentication authentication;
    @Autowired
    private UserTagRepository userTagRepository;
    @Autowired
    private NaritaOperations naritaOperations;
    @Autowired
    private NotificationService notificationService;
    @Autowired
    private TranslationsService translationsService;
    @Autowired
    private ConfigService configService;

    @Autowired
    private NotificationsController notificationsController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testGetConfigMap() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(notificationsController).build();

        try {
            MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(
                    get("/notifications/GENERAL")
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

            ).andReturn();

            assertNotNull(result);
            assertEquals("{\"setting\":\"GENERAL\",\"text\":\"notification.type_general\",\"type\":{\"text\":\"notification.shipments_affected\",\"value\":{\"fe_type\":\"choice\",\"from_values\":[{\"text\":\"notification.shipments_affected_all\",\"value\":\"ALL\"},{\"text\":\"notification.shipments_affected_favorites\",\"value\":\"FAVORITES\"}]}},\"events\":{\"text\":\"notification.events\",\"values\":{\"fe_type\":\"multi_choice\",\"from_values\":[{\"event_type\":\"common\",\"text\":\"notification.triggering_events_status\",\"tooltip\":\"notification.triggering_events_status_tooltip\",\"value\":\"STATUS_CHANGED\",\"default\":true},{\"event_type\":\"common\",\"text\":\"notification.triggering_events_irregularities\",\"tooltip\":\"notification.triggering_events_irregularities_tooltip\",\"value\":\"OPERATIONAL_IRREGULARITIES\",\"default\":true},{\"event_type\":\"milestone\",\"text\":\"notification.triggering_events_pickup\",\"value\":\"PICKUP\"},{\"event_type\":\"milestone\",\"text\":\"notification.triggering_events_export_customs_clearance\",\"value\":\"EXPORT_CUSTOMS_CLEARANCE\"},{\"event_type\":\"milestone\",\"text\":\"notification.triggering_events_origin\",\"value\":\"ORIGIN_PORT\"},{\"event_type\":\"milestone\",\"text\":\"notification.triggering_events_destination\",\"value\":\"DESTINATION_PORT\"},{\"event_type\":\"milestone\",\"text\":\"notification.triggering_events_import_customs_clearance\",\"value\":\"IMPORT_CUSTOMS_CLEARANCE\"},{\"event_type\":\"milestone\",\"text\":\"notification.triggering_events_out_for_delivery\",\"tooltip\":\"notification.triggering_events_out_for_delivery_tooltip\",\"value\":\"OUT_FOR_DELIVERY\"},{\"event_type\":\"milestone\",\"text\":\"notification.triggering_events_customer_delivery\",\"value\":\"CUSTOMER_DELIVERY\"}]}},\"containerLevel\":{\"text\":\"notification.container.choice\",\"tooltip\":\"notification.container.tooltip\",\"fe_type\":\"boolean\",\"value\":false},\"digest\":{\"digest_header\":\"notification.digest_header\",\"digest\":{\"text\":\"notification.digest.all_in_one_mail\",\"fe_type\":\"boolean\",\"value\":false},\"digest_days\":{\"values\":{\"fe_type\":\"multi_choice\",\"from_values\":[{\"text\":\"notification.digest.mondays\",\"value\":\"Mondays\",\"default\":true},{\"text\":\"notification.digest.tuesdays\",\"value\":\"Tuesdays\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"notification.digest.wednesdays\",\"value\":\"Wednesdays\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"notification.digest.thursdays\",\"value\":\"Thursdays\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"notification.digest.fridays\",\"value\":\"Fridays\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"notification.digest.saturdays\",\"value\":\"Saturdays\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"notification.digest.sundays\",\"value\":\"Sundays\",\"default\":false}]}},\"digest_time\":{\"values\":{\"fe_type\":\"choice\",\"from_values\":[{\"text\":\"00:00\",\"value\":\"00:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"00:30\",\"value\":\"00:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"01:00\",\"value\":\"01:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"01:30\",\"value\":\"01:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"02:00\",\"value\":\"02:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"02:30\",\"value\":\"02:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"03:00\",\"value\":\"03:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"03:30\",\"value\":\"03:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"04:00\",\"value\":\"04:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"04:30\",\"value\":\"04:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"05:00\",\"value\":\"05:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"05:30\",\"value\":\"05:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"06:00\",\"value\":\"06:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"06:30\",\"value\":\"06:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"07:00\",\"value\":\"07:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"07:30\",\"value\":\"07:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"08:00\",\"value\":\"08:00\",\"default\":true},{\"text\":\"08:30\",\"value\":\"08:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"09:00\",\"value\":\"09:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"09:30\",\"value\":\"09:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"10:00\",\"value\":\"10:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"10:30\",\"value\":\"10:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"11:00\",\"value\":\"11:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"11:30\",\"value\":\"11:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"12:00\",\"value\":\"12:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"12:30\",\"value\":\"12:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"13:00\",\"value\":\"13:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"13:30\",\"value\":\"13:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"14:00\",\"value\":\"14:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"14:30\",\"value\":\"14:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"15:00\",\"value\":\"15:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"15:30\",\"value\":\"15:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"16:00\",\"value\":\"16:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"16:30\",\"value\":\"16:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"17:00\",\"value\":\"17:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"17:30\",\"value\":\"17:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"18:00\",\"value\":\"18:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"18:30\",\"value\":\"18:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"19:00\",\"value\":\"19:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"19:30\",\"value\":\"19:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"20:00\",\"value\":\"20:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"20:30\",\"value\":\"20:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"21:00\",\"value\":\"21:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"21:30\",\"value\":\"21:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"22:00\",\"value\":\"22:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"22:30\",\"value\":\"22:30\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"23:00\",\"value\":\"23:00\",\"default\":false},{\"text\":\"23:30\",\"value\":\"23:30\",\"default\":false}]}}}}", result.getResponse().getContentAsString());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            fail();
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testGetNotificationRule() {
        User user = mock(User.class);
        when(user.getId()).thenReturn(USER_ID);
        when(authentication.getUser()).thenReturn(user);


        Long id = initDatabase(false);

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(notificationsController).build();

        try {
            MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(
                    get("/notifications/rules/" + id)
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

            ).andReturn();

            assertNotNull(result);

            NotificationRule notificationRule = new ObjectMapper().readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), NotificationRule.class);
            assertNotNull(notificationRule);
            assertEquals(SUBSCRIPTION_ID, notificationRule.getSubscriptionId());
            assertEquals(NotificationSetting.GENERAL, notificationRule.getSetting());
            assertEquals(NotificationType.FAVORITES, notificationRule.getType());

            assertNotNull(notificationRule.getTradeLanes());
            assertEquals(1, notificationRule.getTradeLanes().size());

            for (TradeLane tradeLane : notificationRule.getTradeLanes()) {
                assertNotNull(tradeLane.getOrigin());
                assertEquals(1, tradeLane.getOrigin().size());
                assertNotNull(tradeLane.getDestination());
                assertEquals(1, tradeLane.getDestination().size());
                assertNotNull(tradeLane.getTransportMode());
                assertEquals(1, tradeLane.getTransportMode().size());

                for (PathPoint origin : tradeLane.getOrigin()) {
                    assertEquals("point-name_destination", origin.getName());
                    assertEquals("code-name_destination", origin.getCode());
                }

                for (PathPoint destination : tradeLane.getDestination()) {
                    assertEquals("point-name", destination.getName());
                    assertEquals("code-name", destination.getCode());
                }

                for (TransportMode transportMode : tradeLane.getTransportMode())
                    assertEquals(TransportMode.AIR, transportMode);
            }

            assertTrue(notificationRule.isActive());
            assertTrue(notificationRule.isContainerLevel());

            for (Event event : notificationRule.getEvents()) {
                assertEquals(Event.CUSTOMER_DELIVERY, event);
            }

            assertFalse(notificationRule.isDigest());
            assertEquals("* * * * * * *", notificationRule.getCronSchedule());
            assertEquals("UTC", notificationRule.getTimezone());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            fail();
        }

        clearDatabase();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAllRules() {
        User user = mock(User.class);
        when(user.getId()).thenReturn(USER_ID);
        when(user.getEmail()).thenReturn(USER_EMAIL);
        when(authentication.getUser()).thenReturn(user);

        UserProfileEntity userProfileEntity = getTestUserProfileEntity();
        userProfileRepository.saveAndFlush(userProfileEntity);

        TagsEntity tagsEntity = new TagsEntity();
        tagsEntity.setTag("Tag");
        tagsEntity.setUuid(CPUUID);
        tagsEntity.setUserProfileEntity(userProfileEntity);

        userTagRepository.saveAndFlush(tagsEntity);


        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(notificationsController).build();

        try {
            MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(
                    get("/notifications/all-rules/" + CPUUID + "?cpCode=" + CPCODE)
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

            ).andReturn();

            assertNotNull(result);
            assertNotNull(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
            List allRules = new ObjectMapper().readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(),List.class);
            assertNotNull(allRules);
            assertEquals(1, allRules.size());

            Map data  = (LinkedHashMap)allRules.get(0);
            assertNotNull(data.get("id"));
            assertEquals("12345", data.get("subscriptionId"));
            assertEquals(NotificationSetting.GENERAL.toString(), data.get("setting"));
            assertEquals(NotificationType.FAVORITES.toString(), data.get("type"));
            assertNull(data.get("tradeLanes"));

            assertFalse((Boolean) data.get("active"));
            assertFalse((Boolean) data.get("containerLevel"));
            assertFalse((Boolean) data.get("digest"));

            assertNotNull(data.get("events"));

            List<String> events = (List)data.get("events");

            for(String event : events) {
                assertEquals(Event.STATUS_CHANGED.toString(), event);
            }
            assertNull(data.get("cronSchedule"));
            assertNull(data.get("timezone"));


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        }

        clearDatabase();


    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testCreateNotificationRule() {
        User user = mock(User.class);
        when(user.getId()).thenReturn(USER_ID);
        when(user.getEmail()).thenReturn(USER_EMAIL);
        when(authentication.getUser()).thenReturn(user);

        UserProfileEntity userProfileEntity = getTestUserProfileEntity();
        userProfileRepository.saveAndFlush(userProfileEntity);

        TagsEntity tagsEntity = new TagsEntity();
        tagsEntity.setTag("Tag");
        tagsEntity.setUuid(CPUUID);
        tagsEntity.setUserProfileEntity(userProfileEntity);

        userTagRepository.saveAndFlush(tagsEntity);


        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(notificationsController).build();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        NotificationRule notificationRule = getTestNotificationRule();
        try {
            MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/notifications/rules/" + CPUUID + "?cpCode=" + CPCODE).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(notificationRule))).andReturn();

            assertNotNull(result);
            assertNotNull(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());

            NotificationRule saved = mapper.readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), NotificationRule.class);
            assertNotNull(saved.getId());

            assertEquals("12345", saved.getSubscriptionId());
            assertEquals(NotificationSetting.GENERAL, saved.getSetting());
            assertEquals(NotificationType.FAVORITES, saved.getType());
            assertNull(saved.getTradeLanes());
            assertTrue(saved.isActive());
            assertTrue(saved.isContainerLevel());
            assertNotNull(saved.getEvents());
            assertEquals(1, saved.getEvents().size());

            for (Event event : saved.getEvents()) {
                assertEquals(Event.STATUS_CHANGED, event);
            }

            assertFalse(saved.isDigest());
            assertEquals("* * * * * *", saved.getCronSchedule());
            assertEquals("UTF", saved.getTimezone());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            fail();
        }

        clearDatabase();

    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdateNotificationRule() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(notificationsController).build();

        User user = mock(User.class);
        when(user.getId()).thenReturn(USER_ID);
        when(user.getEmail()).thenReturn(USER_EMAIL);
        when(authentication.getUser()).thenReturn(user);

        Long id = initDatabase(false);

        NotificationRule notificationRule = getTestNotificationRule();
        notificationRule.setId(id);
        notificationRule.setTimezone("GMC");

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(
                    put("/notifications/rules/" + id)
                            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(notificationRule))
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

            ).andReturn();

            assertNotNull(result);

            Optional<NotificationRuleEntity> notificationRuleEntity = notificationRuleRepository.findById(id);

            if (!notificationRuleEntity.isPresent()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Updated rule isnt in database");
            }

            NotificationRuleEntity notificationRuleEntity1 = notificationRuleEntity.get();
            assertEquals("GMC", notificationRuleEntity1.getTimezone());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        }

        clearDatabase();
    }


    @Test
    public void testUpdateNotificationRuleStatus() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(notificationsController).build();

        User user = mock(User.class);
        when(user.getId()).thenReturn(USER_ID);
        when(user.getEmail()).thenReturn(USER_EMAIL);
        when(authentication.getUser()).thenReturn(user);

        Long id = initDatabase(false);

        NotificationRuleStatusChange notificationRuleStatusChange = new NotificationRuleStatusChange();
        notificationRuleStatusChange.setActive(false);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(
                    patch("/notifications/rules/" + id)
                            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(notificationRuleStatusChange))
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

            ).andReturn();

            assertNotNull(result);

            Optional<NotificationRuleEntity> notificationRuleEntity = notificationRuleRepository.findById(id);

            if (!notificationRuleEntity.isPresent()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Updated rule isnt in database");
            }

            NotificationRuleEntity notificationRuleEntity1 = notificationRuleEntity.get();
            assertFalse(notificationRuleEntity1.getActive());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            fail();
        }

        clearDatabase();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeleteNotificationRule() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(notificationsController).build();

        User user = mock(User.class);
        when(user.getId()).thenReturn(USER_ID);
        when(user.getEmail()).thenReturn(USER_EMAIL);
        when(authentication.getUser()).thenReturn(user);

        Long id = initDatabase(true);



        try {
            MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(
                    delete("/notifications/rules/" + id)
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

            ).andReturn();

            assertNotNull(result);

            Optional<NotificationRuleEntity> notificationRuleEntity = notificationRuleRepository.findById(id);

            if (!notificationRuleEntity.isEmpty()) {
                fail();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            fail();
        }

        clearDatabase();
    }

    private void clearDatabase() {
        userTagRepository.deleteAll();
        notificationConfigRepository.deleteAll();
        userProfileRepository.deleteAll();
        notificationRuleRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    private Long initDatabase(boolean isCustomSettings) {
        UserProfileEntity userProfileEntity = getTestUserProfileEntity();
        userProfileRepository.saveAndFlush(userProfileEntity);

        TagsEntity tagsEntity = new TagsEntity();
        tagsEntity.setTag("Tag");
        tagsEntity.setUuid(CPUUID);
        tagsEntity.setUserProfileEntity(userProfileEntity);

        userTagRepository.saveAndFlush(tagsEntity);

        NotificationConfigEntity notificationConfigEntity = getTestNotificationConfigEntity();
        notificationConfigEntity.setUserProfileEntity(userProfileEntity);
        notificationConfigRepository.saveAndFlush(notificationConfigEntity);

        NotificationRuleEntity notificationRuleEntity = getTestNotificationRuleEntity();
        notificationRuleEntity.setNotificationConfigEntity(notificationConfigEntity);

        if(isCustomSettings) {
            notificationRuleEntity.setSetting(NotificationSetting.CUSTOM);
        }

        notificationRuleRepository.saveAndFlush(notificationRuleEntity);

        return notificationRuleEntity.getId();
    }


}
```

I dont know were could be a problem. I check it with another project and It seems that configuration is same. Should it be problem with firewall on jenkins server? But maybe not, becouse another test run smoothly. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to run on a privileged port i.e. one with a number < 1024.

By default the OS will prevent this unless you're running as root.

Setting the port number to a value above 1024 should resolve this.